# Does Google Dataflow supports creating .zip (not .gz) file?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am using google dataflow 1.9.1. Does Google Dataflow supports creating .zip (not .gz) file. I dont see an option in the api docs for .zip generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an [enum](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSink.CompressionType.html), and the [comments in *TextIO.java*](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/e8bf045f6a9ad574780157ca9a1864c0a4f62fea/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L142) suggest *.withCompression* should work. Alas, I don't see the *.withCompression* method. I have filed a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3095) to track.